# Using javascript to set a field (SharePoint 2013 edit item form)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to use client side JScript to set a field, however I am not able to do so. Can someone look at the coding?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setRole() {
    if (ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value = "i:0#.w|mickey.mouse") {
        // Setting the IMORole to Yes
        ctx.CurrentItem["IMORole"].value = "Yes";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong. It should be:

```
if (ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value === "i:0#.w|mickey.mouse") {
        // Setting the IMORole to Yes
        ctx.CurrentItem["IMORole"].value = "Yes";
}
```

Notice the [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `===`.
`=` is for assignment and not comparison.

**Update:**

For finding out whether the value exists in an array or not, you could do one of the following:

1. Using jQuery - [jQuery.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)
   `var exists = $.inArray(value, array);`

Example:

```
var userValue = ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value;
var possibleValues = ["str1", "str2"];

var exists = $.inArray(userValue, possibleValues);
if (exists) {
    ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value = "Yes";
}
```

2. Javascript - [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
   `var exists = arrValues.indexOf('Sam') > -1;`

Example:

```
var userValue = ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value;
var possibleValues = ["str1", "str2"];

var exists = possibleValues.indexOf(userValue) > -1;
if (exists) {
    ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value = "Yes";
}
```

3. Javascript (ES2016) - [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
   `["Sam", "Great", "Sample", "High"].includes("Sam");`

Example:

```
var userValue = ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value;
var possibleValues = ["str1", "str2"];

var exists = possibleValues.includes(userValue);
if (exists) {
    ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value = "Yes";
}
```

Comment: Testing now, what if it is in an array or multiple users?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. Could you please add an example of this in the question?

Comment: The code that you provided, has only one person listed. What if I needed to add additional users?

    if (ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value === "i:0#.w|mickey.mouse","minnie.mouse") {
        // Setting the IMORole to Yes
        ctx.CurrentItem["IMORole"].value = "Yes";

Comment: So this would be the corrected one?

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 SetAField();
});
function SetAField(){
 var userValue = ctx.CurrentItem["loggedonuser"].value;
var possibleValues = ["i:0#.w|1", "i:0#.w|2", "i:0#.w|3"];

var exists = $.inArray(userValue, possibleValues);
if (exists) {
    ctx.CurrentItem["IMORole"].value = "Yes";
}
}
function PreSaveAction(){
 SetAField();
 return true;
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

The example below for your reference:

1.Create a custom list, add a Person or Group field "loggedonuser", add a Yes/No field "IMORole"(default value is No).

2.Add the code below into a script editor web part in the editform.aspx.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var loggedonuser=$("input[name^='loggedonuser'][name$='ClientPeoplePicker_HiddenInput']").val();
    if(loggedonuser.indexOf("i:0#.w|mickey.mouse")!=-1){
        $("input[title='IMORole']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
</script>
```

To get current login name, we can also use REST API to achieve it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var loginName=getUserLoginName(userid);
    if(loginName=="i:0#.w|mickey.mouse"){
        $("input[title='IMORole']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
function getUserLoginName(userId){
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userId + ")";
    // execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            loginName=data.d.LoginName;
        },
        error: function () {            
        }
    });
    return loginName;
}
</script>
```